# Where is this Amazon Sci-Fi series overview image from?

Tags: story-identification

The following picture is used by Amazon for its Sci-Fi series overview.

I'd like to know if it is part of an actual series, if yes, which?

[image: Amazon Sci-Fi series overview image]

Comment: Granted it appears to be a stock image (as answer, below,) but it certainly gives me a rather "Dune-y" vibe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an original image by professional live-action & CG artist [Matjaz Slanic](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/search/photographer?family=creative&photographer=matjaz%20slanic&excludenudity=true&sort=best#license) entitled

> *"Astronaut on distant planet, UFO, concept"*

You can see (and buy the rights to) the original artwork [here](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/photo/astronaut-on-distant-planet-ufo-concept-royalty-free-image/534313736)

[image]

There are other 'astronaut' tagged photos in the same series. This one is probably the closest.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A quick reverse image search on Google seem to indicate this is a stock photo.

[This could be the original source.](https://www.istockphoto.com/it/en/photo/astronaut-on-distant-planet-ufo-concept-gm534313736-94785457)

Therefore, I don't think the image was based on any specific show or book.